# Convert Map<String, String> to List<NameValuePair> - is this the most efficient?

Tags: java

I have a `Map<String, String> pairs` and want to turn this into an `ArrayList` with `NameValuePair` objects. Is this the best way to execute the conversion?

```
List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pairs.entrySet()){
  NameValuePair n = new NameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  nvpList.add(n);
}
```

Comment: Initialize the `ArrayList` with an initial capacity.

Comment: oh yeah just wrote this without a compiler.

Comment: initial capacity equal to the pairs.size()

Comment: Its Map.Entry<,>, see my answer.

Comment: @LeffeBrune yup figured that out too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use NameValuePair, than yes. Only thing I would suggest is creating ArrayList of a size of pairs.size() to avoid overhead of ArrayList resizing internal array multiple times as it grows gradually:

```
List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new ArrayList<>(pairs.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pairs.entrySet()) {
  nvpList.add(new NameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: It's more that I need to do something like this: `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

Answer (score 3):

For future readers:

@Locoboy your code snippet needs some correction and @LeffeBrune's answer will fail since you cannot instantiate an interface.

Need to correct this line:

```
nvpList.add(new NameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

like so:

```
nvpList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

The **BasicNameValuePair** class implements the **NameValuePair** interface so it can be used here.

See full correct code snippet below:

```
public List<NameValuePair> convertToNameValuePair(Map<String, String> pairs) {

    List<NameValuePair> nvpList = new ArrayList<>(pairs.size());

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pairs.entrySet()) {
        nvpList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    return nvpList;
}
```

Comment: That's true only for library versions >= 4.0.  For lower versions (i.e. < 4.0), @LeffeBrune's answer is right (indeed, NameValuePair was a class implementing java.io.Serializable).